# Run node app forever with standard i/o?

Tags: node.js, forever, pm2

I'm really new to node.js.  My friend helped me set up a node app to run a java process I need running on a server at all times.  It works perfectly, except the only way I can see the standard i/o is if I use node app.js.  I've looked into both forever and pm2, however neither of these use standard i/o, which I really need for this server to run commands.  Could somebody help me out please? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the OS you're using, [Writing to stdin of background process](http://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process). You may also consider other methods of accepting input -- notably, a listening [`net.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a ***nix-based server**:

1. You could use **GNU Screen**.

> Screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes, typically interactive shells.

In plain words, you would have access to always-running processes on server and their input-output from your local command line.

After logging in to your server, all you need to do is this:

- Start new screen `screen -S <name>`
- Run you java process
- Detach from screen `screen -d <name>`

That's it! Your java process keeps running and you could interact with it by reattaching to the screen session like this: `screen -r <name>`

Useful Link: [GNU Screen Quick Reference](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference)

Even cooler would be creating your own service using an Upstart script, which you could then call directly from your local machine with:
[Create your own service using Upstart script.](https://gist.github.com/checkaayush/0b370f3ab38f2e403a63)